# System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, frameworks, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

when trying to query my database with entityframework i get the following error:
The navigation property of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[TASK.Warehouses.Domain.NoteProducts.NoteProduct, TASK.Warehouses.Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' is not a single implementation of 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[T]'.
what could be the problem and how could i fix it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote Code-First classes that have `IEnumerable<T>` navigation properties.

Entity Framework requires that your navigation properties be of type `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: ♦: What is the difference? Why should it work with ICollection and not with IEnumerable? I had a project where I used only IEnumerable and it worked perfectly. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have many classes named "TASK.Warehouses.Domain.NoteProducts.NoteProduct, , TASK.Warehouses.Domain]. If this is the case, you are confusing CLR with violations of OO.

Comment: No; those are CLR generic typenames.